# How can I control infile and outfile passed to compiler when specifying files to compile with django-pipeline?

Tags: django

I've written a rudimentary requirejs compiler for Django-Pipeline and I'm trying to polish it up but I'm stuck with a certain problem. I've noticed the same "problem" with the SASS compiler so I wonder if this is a setting I'm missing or something.

```
PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'main': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'sass/main.scss',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/crushcode.css',
        'extra_context': {
            'media': 'screen,projection',
        }
    }
}

PIPELINE_JS = {
    'requirejs': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'js/lib/requirejs-2.0.4.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/require.js',
        'extra_context': {
            'data': '/static/js/bootstrap'
        }
    }
}
```

Both of these create an output file in the source directory of the same name as the input file, with the extension changed to `output_extension` of the respective compiler class. For SASS, this is *ok* as the extension is .css so you end up with main.css next to your main.scss, but with my requirejs plugin the first time I ran it, because the extensions are the same, I actually overwrote my original file (Nothing lost of course, thankyou version control).

I noticed that infile and outfile were both pointing to:

APP_ROOT/static/js/lib/require-2.0.4.js

when I would have thought outfile should point to `output_filename` in the settings.

The easy fix was to change the `output_extension` of my custom compiler class to be 'optimized.js', but at this point I'm adding a .gitignore for every compiled file, and not to mention collectstatic then brings everything across, and also creates the desired output_filename file in the target directory.

What I was hoping for was that collectstatic would simply create the js/require.js file in my `STATIC_ROOT` directory.

It feels like I'm doing something wrong here, any tips? Is this expected behaviour? If so, what's the best should I go about changing it?